# Core partition definition confusion

Tags: number-theory, integer-partitions

I've seen definitions stating that a $t$-core is a partition with no $t$-hook lengths and that a $t$-core is a partition with no hook lengths *divisible* by $t$. Are these definitions equivalent? If so, do you have a reference to cite?

Comment: By "no $t$-hook lengths" do you mean no hooks of length *exactly* $t$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: At first I was *highly* skeptical that the two are equivalent. But now, I actually do believe it's true. I don't have a rigorous argument or a reference, but I'm trying to draw a tableaux with the upper-left box having hook length $6$, and no boxes with hook length $3$, and I don't think it's possible. Basically $\matrix{\square \square \square}$,$\matrix{\square & \kern{-1em} \square \\[-1 em] \square &}$, and $\matrix{\square \\[-1em] \square \\[-1em] \square}$ become "forbidden" sub-bottom-right-tableaux in some hard-to-describe sense, but I don't think we can avoid them.

Comment: Yes, I just found a paper by Stanley that says they're equivalent. I think that if hook length $h$ appears, then any divisor of $h$ must too. But I can't find where I read that.

Answer (score 0):

*The Representation Theory of the Symmetric Group*, James and Kerber, [doi:10.1017/CBO9781107340732](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781107340732), section 2.7.

A $q$*-hook* is defined at the start of the section as a hook of length $q$. The following paragraph defines a $q$*-core* as a diagram $[\alpha]$ which does not contain any $q$-hook, and says that the same name will be used for the corresponding partition $\alpha$. Then 10 pages later we have

> **2.7.40** The $q$-weight of a diagram equals the number of hook lengths divisible by $q$. In particular, $[\alpha]$ is a $q$-core iff no hook length is divisible by $q$.